# How does Liferay login work?

Tags: java, session, authentication, liferay

Just as the user jack wants to do in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096360/liferay-login-programatically) post, I need to do a portlet that uses login through token authentication.
As is stated there, `portal-impl.jar` is unavailable for me to use, so `LoginUtil.login` is unaccessible.
Additionally, adding functionality to the existing `ext plugin` is almost out of the question because he's waaaay to 'dense', and creating another one is a bad practice.
So i chose to create my own login function based on the `login()` logic in `LoginUtil`. It's basically the same code but with the required `portal-impl.jar`'s properties stored locally (upgrade to a newer Liferay version is out of the question so I think it's ok to do that).
Everything seems to work fine, however I am not logged in and no error apperas in Tomcat.

Now, my problem is that I can't realise what piece of the code actually logs the user in.
I assume it's this

```
        session.setAttribute("j_username", userIdString);
        session.setAttribute("j_password", user.getPassword());
        session.setAttribute("j_remoteuser", userIdString);

        session.setAttribute(WebKeys.USER_PASSWORD, password);
```

PS : After my custom login method (which I repeat, it has the same code as LoginUtil's login method), if I put the following code :

```
ThemeDisplay td = (ThemeDisplay) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
User uu = td.getUser();
System.out.println("user = " + uu.getEmailAddress());
```

it will output `user = default@liferay.com`, so the login is unsuccessful.
Where is the user logged in in that code?!

PPS:
in my portal-ext.properties, here are the following add-ons:

`auth.pipeline.enable.liferay.check=false

session.enable.persistent.cookies=true

session.enable.phishing.protection=false

session.disabled=false

session.test.cookie.support=true`

My version of Liferay is 5.2.3.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but my opinion, the better and simplest way is to create a new hook with AutoLogin funktion: [How do I use autologin in liferay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787586/how-do-i-use-autologin-in-liferay)

ps: and then you are upgrade stable.